# Remove/Drop stage in snowflake after use

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created an internal temporary stage in snowflake and after consuming data from it. I want to remove the stage.

I have created stage as:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE TEST_STAGE COMMENT = 'TEMPORARY STAGE FOR USER DATA LOAD'
```

When I do:

```
SHOW STAGES IN ACCOUNT;
```

I see:

```
name         database_name   schema_name   type
TEMP_STAGE    test            schema       internal_temporary
```

all other fields related to s3 are null since its internal storage.

I have tried

```
DROP STAGE "test"."schema"."TEMP_STAGE"


remove @%USER;
```

None of them worked, I still see this stage using show stages command. And I have proper rights to delete the schema

Answer (score 0):

stage created as temporary will be dropped at the end of the session in which it was created.

Please Note:

1. When a temporary external stage is dropped, only the stage itself is
   dropped; the data files are not removed.
2. When a temporary internal stage is dropped, all of the files in the
   stage are purged from Snowflake, regardless of their load status.
   This prevents files in temporary internal stages from using data storage and, consequently, accruing storage charges. However, this
   also means that the staged files cannot be recovered through
   Snowflake once the stage is dropped.

Tip: *If you plan to create and use temporary internal stages, you should maintain copies of your data files outside of Snowflake.*